# как сделать вывод html в php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, переменные

Здраствуйте, хотелось бы узнать. Возможно ли в php вывести html код в не стандартном формате. я пишу движок статей для сайта, и сделал небольшой код.

```
  //  print_r($_POST);
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $num = $_POST['postnum'];
  $file = "$num.php";
//если файла нету... тогда
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "w"); // ("r" - считывать "w" - создавать "a" - добавлять к тексту),мы создаем файл
    fwrite($fp, "<h1>$name</h1> <h3>$message</h3>");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

в fwrite мне нужно каким-то образом вывести полноценный html код. После появления хоть одной " весь код ломается. и желательно чтобы так-же выводились переменные.

Comment: может экранировать кавычки,если с ними проблема.

Comment: или шаблонизатор какой-то

Answer (score 0):

При использовании одинарных кавычек код интерпретируется как текст, а при использовании двойных он соответственно будет выполняться.

Приведу пример:

```
$language = 'English';
echo '$language';
        
// Output: $language
        
    
$language = 'English';
echo "$language";
        
// Output: English
```

Comment: выполняться --> подставляться значение переменной